# Read a file only one time

Tags: python

I made a script in Java which writes to a file the following (java) list:

```
[-215 62 -155, -215 63 -155, -215 64 -155, -215 65 -155, -215 66 -155]
```

My Python script needs to **READ** that file as follows without modifying the file or creating a new one:

```
-215 62 -155
-215 63 -155
-215 64 -155
-215 65 -155
-215 66 -155
```

I made this Python script which converts the string to a list:

```
input_file = open('C:/test.txt', 'rb')

for line in input_file:
    blocks = line.split(",")

#Delete brackets
blocks[0] = blocks[0][1:]
blocks[len(blocks)-1] = blocks[len(blocks)-1].strip()[:-1]

for data in blocks:
    print data.split()
```

Output:

```
['-215', '62', '-155']
['-215', '63', '-155']
['-215', '64', '-155']
['-215', '65', '-155']
['-215', '66', '-155']
```

As you can see the process is not over, I need to remove the brackets and the quotation marks making the execution slower.

Things I tried:

- Enumerate(): but it is not recognizing the format
- Write the list as the desired output in Java: appending each item to the file takes forever.
- Store the position of the comas in a list and with the find() function loop trough the string: but the algorithm loops two times over the file.

The original file has 9 million items. So, my question is: **It is possible to loop only one time?**

Comment: Change `print data.split()[0:3]` to `print data`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice my original file has 2 more values thats why im slicing it, but im going to edit that part. thanks!

Comment: Also, what is the reason for using multiple languages for this problem? Perhaps you need to look at the output from your Java program and have it create the correct output directly. It sounds like you have tried this. Go ahead and post a new question with your Java code to illustrate your problem there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, im going to add the java code to my question, but what i but i need Python to read it as described in my question.

Comment: You should create a new question with your Java code, not add it to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suspect that you could more easily create the correct output directly from your Java program. If you want help with that, please post a new question with your Java code illustrating what you are trying to do there.

To answer this question directly, the problem is that `print()` calls `str()` to create a string representation of your list. This adds the brackets and commas. Most likely a recursive call to `str()` on the elements of the list add the single-quotes around the string elements.

To fix this problem, you can iterate over the result of the `split()` and print out each element manually:

```
for data in blocks:
    values = data.split()
    for v in values:
        print(v, end=" ")
    print()
```

This will leave an extra space at the end of each line. With a little bit of work, you should be able to fix that problem, if needed.

Comment: @syrux I'm not sure what difference that makes. The exact details might change (perhaps `end` isn't available?), but the general solution is still the same: loop through the result of the `split()` yourself.

Comment: I found the solution -print ", ".join(data.split())- thanks to your explanation: "the problem is that print() calls str() to create a string representation of your list" Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        result = line.strip('[]') # strip out the beginning and ending brackets
        for out_line in result.split(','):
            outfile.write(out_line + "\n")
```

This will take your single line 9,000,000 item java list literal and turn it into the table you asked for in a new file.

Comment: Your answer is a two steps solution. I'm asking if I can do it one time.

Comment: Can you read my first comment?, I don't understand your "single line 9,000,000 item java list literal" joke.

Comment: @syrux that's not a joke, that's what you described in your question.... If your input file is NOT a single line file, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish....

Comment: Shame I don't have 125.

Comment: @syrux if I misunderstood your question, you could clarify it. Otherwise I'm not really sure what you're trying to do since you listed your input as a long list from Java, then mentioned you have a 9,000,000 item long input....